# Google Chrome Version 34.0.1847.116 m no longer passing the selected value of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

For several years I've been able to use the qForms JavaScript library and oForm.required("payOnline"); to test for at least one radio button being selected.  It continues to work in every browser except the latest version of Google Chrome.  Chrome says no radio button has been selected.

Anyone seen a similar issue?  Nearly a year ago Google introduced a similar but in radio buttons where autofill would clear radio button selections.

Comment: I haven't seen this issue, but I have heard of many other problems (just look in new questions here) caused by this version of chrome.  One problem I brought up is the problem with the 'proceed' chrome builtin hack.

Comment: Well is breaks many legacy apps across my entire site.  I use qForms which looks at the value of the selected radio button to validate other form fields.  Without that value being passed, validation appears to pass and flow continues, incorrectly.

Comment: Ooo... That's not good.  Maybe you should send a bug report to google, and let them know about this, I am sure they will want to hear about this.

Comment: I found someone in the same situation yesterday who did file a bug report.  Google claims they made the change to radio buttons to be more compliant with the HTML specs.  However no other browser has done this so only Chrome is now broken.  We were able to rework the validation library to work with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

My system started experiencing this as well.  Any chance you can share how you reworked the library?